# Rails closure_tree - how do I add Devise method current_user to Create action in PostsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested

I built nested posts using this closure_tree tutorial:

[Nested Comments with Rails - Sitepoint][1]

Then I installed Devise and began attributing posts to users in the PostsController and Post & User models. How can I add the current_user method to the Create action (the 'if' portion, not the 'else' portion) in my PostsController so I can track the creator of a post which has replies? I have tried several combinations including:

```
 @post = current_user.parent.children.build(post params)
 @post = current_user.posts.parent.children.build(post params)
```

They are all throwing errors.

Here is my code:

```
Post.rb

    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC'

end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

    def index
        @post = Post.new
        @posts = Post.hash_tree
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
    end

    def create
        if params[:post][:parent_id].to_i > 0
            parent = Post.find_by_id(params[:post].delete(:parent_id))
            @post = parent.children.build(post_params)
        else
            @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        end

        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = 'Your post was successfully added!'
            redirect_to posts_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end

end
```

_Post.html.erb partial

```
   <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <%= post.content %></br>
        <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(post.created_at), post_path(post) %> ago by <%= post.user.name.capitalize %> | <% from_reply_form ||= nil %>
    <% unless from_reply_form %>
      <%= link_to 'reply', new_post_path(post.id) %>
    <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!!!

```
`ThreadedSalesApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :create]
  get '/posts/new/(:parent_id)', to: 'posts#new', as: :new_post

  root     'posts#index'


end`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to merge the user_id: with the post_params, and when calling the user in the post index view I needed to use post.user.name versus user.name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of an issue understanding what is your post nested under? The tutorial you referenced shows how to nest comments. Comments *could* be nested under posts. I'm sure others will be more helpful than I am given my limited experience but from what I can see, your methods are wrong. Consider the following:

```
def index
@post = Post.new
@posts = Post.hash_tree
end
```

In your index, you ought to show an *index* (think of it as a list) of your objects, in this case it would be the list of Posts. You're initiating a new post which should happen in your 'new' method. In the tutorial you referenced, you'll notice that index is defined as:

```
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
```

To give you an **example**, if we're nesting posts under Topics, your code could look something like this:

```
class Topics::PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
  end

    def create
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
      @post.topic = @topic 

        if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your post was successfully added!"
        redirect_to [@topic, @post]
        else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your post."
        render :new
        end
    end
...
```

Basically, if your posts are nested under something else, you must find that object's ID first to nest it under that. The same could be done with comments (comments being nested under your posts). You would look for the post_id in your Comments Controller.

Comment: Thank you. I am using posts#index as my root view, and overall goal is to create a simple Facebook-like feed where users can initiate a post from the same root index page they view the feed from. That is why my index action has post = Post.new included. In the tutorial, there are two parts, and in the second part he augments the index action from post = Post.all to post.hash_tree which is a method from the closure_tree gem. (the only thing I did diff from his tutorial is rename comments to posts). My app is working well except for fact I can't track replies to initial comments.